# How to rearrange an array of structures into alphabetical order

Tags: arrays, string, comparison, structure

so lets say you have

and no loops, i could compare them and see if they are the same or not...

```
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would use the `qsort` library function. Here's a Q&A that explains it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846508/using-a-qsort-to-sort-struct-pointers-by-different-variables

Comment: i am unfamiliar with such, i was hoping to fall more into the bubble sort area. i already have a working bubble sort written, in the beginning of the program i use it to sort my arrary of structures by the grade average... anyways i can simply manipulate that to work for the name?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that part of the code. The compare can be done with `strcmp`, for example `if (strcmp(student[i].name, student[i-1].name) > 0 )`

Comment: looking through this... it seems like theres nothing about the loop. the file i have can have any amount of lines of data... this makes things a little more complicating. i can't even lie, im at a total loss of where to being. even after reading the post you suggested.

Comment: @user3386109 okay, so what is the > 0 saying? and is this a line that i can  plug into my bubble sort?

Comment: Yes, just replace the `if` in the bubble sort with the `if` in my comment.

Comment: @user3386109 once again, im getting a segmentation fault... ill update the code with what my sort looks like, maybe you can see something i dont.

Comment: The letter `i` is just a generic array index. Your *actual* array index is called `walker`.

Comment: but dont i need to keep those i's in my print statement to keep up with the how many records it's printing...

Comment: i mean, looking at the code from before, it seems correct. because in my earlier bubble sort i use walker and such, then when i print it in order by average i use the i's. it all looks identical, just this time in the same function.

Comment: @user3386109 -.- sometimes i just need to slow down and actually read what you're telling me.

Comment: LOL, you do seem to be behaving like you're very, very tired and have been drinking way too much caffeine :)

Comment: lots of coffee... but from the two posts' that you have assisted me with, i no longer require help. the rest is clean up. you're a life saver, and not only were my questions answered, but you allowed me to understand what and why i was doing it. thank you again! super helpful!

Comment: You're welcome, cheers!

Comment: @user3386109 if you're available, i've posted a question that nobody is seeming to respond to. feel free to jump on :')